# Multi variable output on pandas rolling apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate a few polynomial regressions on a pandas rolling window, however it seems that I can only get a single value rather than all the ones that the regressions returns.

```
df['poly'] = df.rolling(window = i)['Col'].apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(np.array(range(0,i)), x, 9), raw=True)
```

for which I get:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is there any way to get all the coefficients from this apply?

Comment: This is a current limitation withing the window functions. They can only be aggregating functions that returns a single value for each window. Consider implementing a customized rollapply

Comment: I have tried to apply the coefficients to a list and then apply this to the df, however i can't given they have different indexes/sizes.

Comment: You do need to write a for-loop. That the notion of `customized` window operations

Comment: A for loop reading each coefficient? if so, please note that there is a ton of data, each regression takes quite a while.

Comment: The for loop is to run the models and not read the coeficients

Comment: can you please elaborate on the idea?